# Asus ZenBook UX325SA_UM325SA Keyboard Not Working After shutdown

Tags: keyboard, asus, 22.04

I am not quite sure if i'll explain the problem correctly, but here it goes. I have installed 22.04 LTS ubuntu on my Asus ZenBook UX325SA_UM325SA. during the installation i could not use my keyboard so i plugged in my usb keyboard to complete the installation. After the install keyboard still did not respond but if i restarted the machine all worked fine. and as long as i restart a machine after shutdown keyboard works but never directly after shut down.

i tried to do:
[this](https://www.cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipns/anthonyrussano.com/asus-zenbook-keyboard-not-working-after-fresh-ubuntu-install/)
and follow instructions
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360683/keyboard-not-working-after-shutdown-asus-zenbook-13-oled-um325s)

but no luck. some additional information:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop i8042.probe_defer"
```

```
xinput list
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i keyboard
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
N: Name="ASUE140A:00 04F3:3134 Keyboard"
```

any idea what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I started having the same issue on a Lenovo ThinkPad X13 Gen1, where keyboard, trackpad, and trackpoint stopped randomly working, and the `i8042.c: Can't read CTR while initializing i8042` message started appearing on boot.

In my case simply adding `i8042.probe_defer` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` fixed it, even though the error message keeps appearing at boot.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.probe_defer"
```

I wonder if, in your case, adding all the options at once somehow made the `probe_defer` option not effective.